# Does anybody know this voice effect?

Tags: effects, vocals, replication

Does anybody know the voice effect used in this video. Please I've been searching for over a year. I love this effect but I can't get an answer to as what it's called. Here is the link:

http://youtube.com/watch?v=D-SQqppuGvc

Answer (score 2):

**[Auto-Tune](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-Tune)**

First made popular in the late 90s on [Cher's "Believe"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Believe_(Cher_song))

The product was initially designed to mask slight imperfections in a singer's pitching, but it was discovered that by turning everything up as hard & fast as it would go, a new effect could be created, making the voice sound synthesised.

Since the original Auto-Tune, there have been many similar products made, including [Melodyne](http://www.celemony.com/en/start) which allows you to completely re-draw the pitches & durations, including duplicating pitches to make harmonies - & may actually be the tool used on that track. It's hard to tell which is which by ear alone.